# comment edited 1 минуту назад

Tags: дефект, локализация, правки

После редактирования комментария у [правки](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1020444/revisions) к нему добавляется надписть

> (comment edited 1 минуту назад)

[image: скриншот]

Надо бы перевести.

Comment: Либо этой строки нет в транзифексе, либо не подхватывется, потому что [вот](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=comment%20edited) всё что доступно - переведено.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ вполне вероятно, что она хардкодится в момент редактирования и не локализуется вовсе.

Comment: @Suvitruf на момент редактирования должно локализоваться всё же.

Comment: @Suvitruf, не может быть - время же обновляется.

Comment: @Suvitruf, ничего не изменилось: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbVtm.png