# Правка комментария правки отображается не сразу

Tags: дефект, инструменты-модератора

Информация о правке комментария правки (которая, кстати, до сих пор [не переведена](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9482/178988)) появляется не сразу, а только после обновления страницы:

> (comment edited 9 минут назад)

[image: скриншот]